# I am getting thread1:SIGNAL sigbart in output

Tags: c++, binary, xcode4.2, generator, sequence

this is my code, PLease help me ! im using xcode.. i want to generate a sequence for a polynomial and the terms are xor'ed and made a feedback to the first input bit since it is 8 bit it is done 2^8-1 times.Alternate code will also be helpful Thanks in advance

```
#include "32bit.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool input[8];
    int n;
    bool out=0;
    cout<<"Enter the no of terms ";
    cin>>n;
    int temp1[n];
    int gen=0;
    bool store[255];
    cout<<"Input power of x in increasing order, Omit x^0";


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>temp1[i];
    cout<<"Enter key to generate ";
    cin>>gen;
    for(int m=0;m<255;m++)
    {
        store[m]=input[gen];
        bool temp2[n];
        int var=0;
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {

            var=temp1[j];
            temp2[j]=input[var];
        }
        int c=0;
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(temp2[k]%2==1)
                c++;

        }
        if(c%2==1)
            out=1;
        else
            out=0;
        for(int l=0;l<8;l++)
            input[l+1]=input[l];
        input[0]=out;
    }
    for(int p=0;p<255;p++)
        cout<<store[p];
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this in debug mode ? Which line does the debugger stop at ?

Comment: at the last line of code

Answer (score 0):

There is an out of bounds array access here:

```
    for(int l=0;l<8;l++)
        input[l+1]=input[l];
```

since `input` is only of size 8 and you are trying to write to `input[8]` (i.e. the non-existent 9th element) on the last iteration of this loop. I'm guessing it should probably be:

```
    for(int l=0;l<7;l++)
        input[l+1]=input[l];
```

Comment: thanks but this didnt correct it. i have a doubt.. Can we do 
cin>>n;
bool temp[n]; in c++ .. or do we have to do it dynamically ?